# Drag textbox in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I wanted to ask how to move a textbox which is a child of a grid. This Code changes the left of the TextBox but it doesn't move it. Is there a way to set the parent of my textbox to a canvas. Thank for your response in advance.

```
private void Handle_Drag(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox Text = sender as TextBox;

    Text.Text = "I'm moved";
    double currentX = Canvas.GetLeft(Text);
    double currentY = Canvas.GetTop(Text);

    MessageBox.Show(currentX.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(currentY.ToString()); 

    Canvas.SetLeft(Text, currentX + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(Text, currentY + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y); 
}
```

Comment: Your `TextBox` needs to be a child of the `Canvas` to move it on the `Canvas`. If you want to move it to the `Canvas`, you'll need to first remove it from the `Grid` and then add it to the `Canvas`: `Canvas.Children.Add(Text)`. However, you'd need to do that in the `Drop` handler and not the `Drag` handler. If you just want to have a visual representation of the `TextBox` as you move it, then you'll need to search for `Adorner`s instead.

Comment: I tried             
ContentGrid.Children.Remove(Text); 
myCanvas.Children.Add(Text); but it doesn' t seem to work. The Error says that Text still is a child of another element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the parent of textbox and remove it from that grid.

```
   private void Handle_Drag(object sender,System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Text = sender as TextBox;

        var parent = Text.Parent as Grid;
        if (parent  != null)
        {
            parent.Children.Remove(Text);
            myCanvas.Children.Add(Text);
        }

        Text.Text = "I'm moved";
        double currentX = Canvas.GetLeft(Text);
        double currentY = Canvas.GetTop(Text);

        MessageBox.Show(currentX.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(currentY.ToString());

        Canvas.SetLeft(Text, currentX + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(Text, currentY + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y); 
    }
```

Or you can use interaction behaviors API to drag. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Drag_%26_Drop_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: @10denz If this is what you are looking for, accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set parent of TextBox as null

```
Text.Parent = null;
```

Then add TextBox as child of desired Canvas

`desiredCanvas.Children.Add(Text);`

( assuming name of the Canvas is Name="desiredCanvas" )